# AWS SES - Send email with different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I have two accounts in an organization. In the main account I have set up the domain and verified it.
Furthermore I've set up credentials and can send over my EC2 instance in account 1.

Now I have the second account with EC2 instances which I want to send mail with without verifying the domain again. I have set up credentials there, too.

I actually thought that it had to go through the identity policies, but even after I entered the second account in account 1, I couldn't send anything over account 2. But if I verify the domain on the second account, it is possible for me to send mails.

This policy was created from the generator:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "xxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT2:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:eu-central-1:ACCOUNT1:identity/DOMAIN"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I use the identity policy to send mails from my domain and the second account without verifying the domain there again?

Answer (score 0):

Emails need to be verified in the account from which the email is being sent via SES.

One solution to your scenario (which I appreciate is a few years old) is to create an IAM role (ROLE1) in ACCOUNT1 (that the domain is verified in) with the assume role policy:

```json
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "arn:aws:iam:eu-central-1:ACCOUNT-2:role/ROLE2"
    ]
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
```

and with the permissions:

```json
{
  “Sid”: “AllowSendEmail”,
  “Effect”: “Allow”,
  “Action”: [
    “ses:SendEmail”,
    “ses:SendRawEmail”
  ],
  “Resource”: [
    “arn:aws:ses:eu-central-1:ACCOUNT-1:identity/DOMAIN”
  ]
}
```

and then create a role in ACCOUNT2 which can assume ROLE1.

---

With this set up you'll be able to use ROLE2 to assume ROLE1, with which you can call `ses:SendEmail`.